# libgdx: Images don't disappear when I switch screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx

At this moment I have 2 screens: `MainScreen` (it's the main menu of the game) and `GameScreen`. I have a "button" (it's an image) that when the user clicks on it, the `MainScreen` switchs to the `GameScreen`.

The problem is that all the images of the `MainScreen` don't disappear when the second screen appears (the button and the main title). I have been working on this for days and I don't know what more to do.

Main class of the game:

```
public class MyGame extends Game {

    @Override
    public void create () {
        Sounds.load();
        Texts.load();
        Buttons.load();

        setScreen(new MainScreen(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        super.dispose();
        Sounds.dispose();
        Texts.dispose();
        Buttons.dispose();
    }
}
```

MainScreen:

```
public class MainScreen implements Screen {

    private MyGame game;

    private Stage stage;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Viewport viewport;

    public static Image tituloPrincipal, botonPlay;



    public MainScreen(final MyGame game) {

        this.game = game;

        //stage
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Settings.SCREEN_WIDTH, Settings.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        viewport = new StretchViewport(Settings.SCREEN_WIDTH, Settings.SCREEN_HEIGHT, camera);
        stage = new Stage(viewport);

        //background
        stage.addActor(new Image(Sprites.mainBackground));

        //Title of the game
        tituloPrincipal = new Image();
        tituloPrincipal.setPosition(Settings.SCREEN_WIDTH  * 1 / 6, Settings.SCREEN_HEIGHT * 4 / 12);
        tituloPrincipal.setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(Texts.tituloPrincipal)));
        tituloPrincipal.setSize(Texts.tituloPrincipal.getWidth()/3,
                Texts.tituloPrincipal.getHeight()/3);
        stage.addActor(tituloPrincipal);

        //Play Button
        botonPlay = new Image();
        botonPlay.setPosition(Settings.SCREEN_WIDTH  * 4 / 10, Settings.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 16);
        botonPlay.setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(Buttons.playbutton)));
        botonPlay.setSize(Buttons.playbutton.getWidth()/16,
                Buttons.playbutton.getHeight()/18);

        stage.addActor(botonPlay);


        //Song
        Sounds.musicMainScreen.play();


    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        botonPlay.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
                dispose();
            }
        });


            stage.draw();
            stage.act(delta);


    }

    @Override
    public void resize ( int width, int height){

    }

    @Override
    public void pause () {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume () {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide () {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {

    }
}
```

GameScreen:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
    private Game game;
    private Stage stage;

    public GameScreen(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
        stage = new Stage();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        deleteMainScreenSources();


        //song
        Sounds.musicGameScreen.play();

    }

    public void deleteMainScreenSources() {
        Sounds.musicMainScreen.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {


    }

    @Override
    public void resize ( int width, int height){

    }

    @Override
    public void pause () {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume () {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide () {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {

    }
}
```

Button class:

```
public class Buttons {
    public static Texture playbutton;


    public static void load() {
        playbutton = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("playbutton.png"));
        playbutton.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest, Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest);

    }

    public static void dispose() {
        playbutton.dispose();
    }

}
```

The class of the title it's like the class of the button.

Comment: Can you try clearing the screen in your render method of GameScreen ? something like this `Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `render` method is what draws your screen. If you are not aware, it is kind of a game loop , which gets executed non stop ( around 60/sec by default I believe).  So all your drawing and redrawing goes here.Usually ,  you would be clearing your screen at first and then draw other images on the screen. Libgdx provide interfacing to opengl to clear the screen. In my case, I always clear screen at the very first line of `render` method and draw additional things on it so that it makes sure my stale content of the screens are gone.In your `GameScreen` , your `render` method is empty , so your previous screen is not yet wiped out. I believe adding clear and drawing your new stage in GameScreen will resolve your issue.

Make your code in GameScreen render something like this and try ,

```
 @Override
public void render(float delta) {
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
stage.act();
stage.draw();

}
```

Also, I would try to avoid creation of any new object in 'render` method for the same reason. Your addListener method in your menu screen can go in it's constructor. So that you don't create anonymous listener in every game loop execution. This may not impact by that much in your current scenario, but if you create some heavy object or some Sprites in this way in game loop, that can drag your game perfomance a lot.

Comment: Thank you VERY much sir! Now I think it's working perfecty fine. So much hours for such a little thing... Thanks!

Comment: glad I was able to help.